# Dart: updating a list inside a List<List<String>> causes a sibling list to be updated as well

Tags: arrays, list, dart, pass-by-reference

in Dart if I have a multidimensional List of strings and I want to add elements to an inside list, it causes all the lists to have the same elements, below is a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  List<String> teachers = [
    'John',
    'Chris',
    'Michael',
    'Eli',
    'Jerry',
    'Cary',
    'Jimmy'
  ];
  List<List<String>> rooms = List.filled(2, <String>[]);

  List<String> usedTeachers = List.from(teachers);

  for (int roomIndex = 0; roomIndex < rooms.length; roomIndex++) {
    rooms[roomIndex].clear();
    rooms[roomIndex]
        .addAll([usedTeachers.removeAt(0), usedTeachers.removeAt(0)]);
  }
  print(rooms);
}
```

what I expect is the following:

- In the first iteration, it will pop/remove the first 2 elements from the `usedTeachers` list and add them to the first list so it should have ['John','Chris'];
- In the second iteration, it will pop/remove the second 2 elements from the `usedTeachers` list and add them to the second list so it should have ['Michael','Eli']

The final `rooms` list should look like this:

`[['John','Chris'],['Michael','Eli']]`

Instead it result in this:

`[['Michael','Eli'],['Michael','Eli']]`

So the final iteration always causes all the lists to have the same elements

It looks like some pass by reference/pass by value issue, but I'm deep cloning the list when possible so I'm not sure what's the issue

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is caused by the `List.filled` constructor which fills the list with the same element(same memory address) so when I update on element it will reflect in all lists
Changing the line:

`List<List<String>> rooms = List.filled(2, <String>[]);`

To this:

`List<List<String>> rooms = List.generate(2, (index) => ['1', '2']);`

Solves the issue